# Auto indentation of pasted python code in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, indentation, auto-indent

A problem to which many threads exist, but I still could not figure out how to get it working.

When I paste code (e.g. a whole method I got returned from ChatGPT) and paste it into my code, the indentation must be corrected:

```
    def message(self, message, filler="-", newline=True):
        """
Display a message in the console, formatted to fit within the width.
:param message: The message to display.
:param filler: The filler character to use for padding.
:param newline: Whether to print a newline after the message.
"""

        max_messagelen = self.width-4
        if len(message) > max_messagelen:
            message_words = message.split()
```

In this example, I had dcostrings generated form ChatGPT and wanted to paste them into my function.

I would like my input code to be adjusted to the indentation of the line where I am pasting it.
So every following line of the pasted code should get the same amount of indentation, a pretty straightforward problem.

I would like to bring this to a custom shortcut, so I still have normal pasting and correct-indent-pasting.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click in the file then choose Format Document With...

[image]

In the list, choose Python will format your codes.

[image]

[image]

You can change your default Formatter to **Python**, or add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```
  "[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python"
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

In this way, when you use shortcuts **Ctrl+S**, file will be formatted as you want.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but this does not answer my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/):

Go to the Extension bar and install Python Paste And Indent.

Also the only thing to do for one your showing is to delete an indent.